# Tmux Window Closes when I ":q" a vim file.

Tags: vim, tmux

Maybe I have it configured wrong.. maybe I just don't know much about Tmux and Vim.. (most likely both).

But when I create multiple panels in Tmux, then launch vim in one, edit the file, save & exit - all panels are closed along with the file edited.

Case Example: 
I have; Session("Development") with one Window("MyProject1"), and two panels - each with their own file (*.cpp/*.h, or *.html/*.css, etc).

If I save and close one of the files (vim:wq), both panels close.  Why is that?  What can I do to maintain the side panels active within the window?

Comment: all I can say is that it does not behave like this for me. What do you have in your tmux.conf? Also, is it intended that your panel closes when exiting vim? If yes, how did you configure it?

Comment: tmux_conf_theme=default
tmux_conf_theme_prefix=disabled
tmux_conf_theme_battery=enabled
tmux_conf_battery_style=bar
tmux_conf_battery_symbol=block
tmux_conf_battery_symbol_count=auto
tmux_conf_battery_palette='#d70000,#e4e4e4,#000000'
tmux_conf_battery_status=enabled
tmux_conf_theme_time=enabled
tmux_conf_theme_date=enabled
tmux_conf_theme_username=enabled
tmux_conf_theme_hostname=enabled
tmux_conf_theme_highlight_focused_pane=disabled
tmux_conf_new_windows_retain_current_path=false
tmux_conf_new_panes_retain_current_path=true
tmux_conf_new_session_prompt=false

Comment: Maybe this is more relevant..  (vim conf) 

" Tmux integration
if &term =~ '^screen'
    " tmux will send xterm-style keys when xterm-keys is on
    execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
    execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
    execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
    execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
endif

" Close tmux when exiting vim
autocmd VimLeave * silent !tmux killp -a

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my Vim Config had this line:

```
" Close tmux when exiting vim
autocmd VimLeave * silent !tmux killp -a
```

I commented it out and now the panel remains in place after I close vim files.

Thanks for participating!